# Deduce that π/4 = 1 − 1/3 + 1/5 − 1/7 + · · · .

Tags: fourier-transform

This is a question from Transform Theory, Fourier Series. I'm not exactly sure how to go about it. How do you prove that

$\frac{\pi}{4} = 1 - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5}- \frac{1}{7}\ + ...$

Comment: Look at the Fourier series of the $1$-periodic function $f(x) = 1$ for $x \in [-1/4,1/4], f(x) = 0$ for $x \in [1/4,3/4]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
{\pi \over 4} = \int_{0}^{1}{\mathrm{d}t \over 1 + t^{2}} =
\int_{0}^{1}\left(1 - t^{2} + t^{4} - t^{6} + \cdots\right)\,\mathrm{d}t
$$

> This is Leibniz series !!!.

Comment: Okay. I see. I had to do a bit more digging but this put me in the right direction. Rewriting π/4 as arctan(x) and then rewriting that as a geometric progression of (-x^2) and integrating the terms individually. Thanks for this.

Comment: @Sithe You're welcome. Thanks.